# Thread Locking issue with SmartXLS

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-safety, smartxls

WE have been seeing issue with SmartXLS when we run it with multi threaded environment, does anyone have seen issue? 
we are using java 1.7
SmartXLS 4.6

```
 java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at com.smartxls.a.aj.a(SourceFile:44)
    - waiting to lock <6521da27> (a com.smartxls.a.ai$a) owned by "GS-jobListenerPollingContainer-3" t@70
    at com.smartxls.a.aj.a(SourceFile:38)
    at com.smartxls.a.aj.a(SourceFile:28)
    at com.smartxls.a.de.a(SourceFile:173)
    at com.smartxls.a.de.a(SourceFile:97)
    at com.smartxls.a.y.T(SourceFile:1598)
    at com.smartxls.a.y.Q(SourceFile:1340)
    at com.smartxls.a.bq.a(SourceFile:391)
    at com.smartxls.a.h.b(SourceFile:1220)
    at com.smartxls.a.h.a(SourceFile:279)
    at com.smartxls.ss.af.f(SourceFile:2009)
    at com.smartxls.ss.af.a(SourceFile:2635)
    at com.smartxls.ss.af.b(SourceFile:2673)
    at com.smartxls.ss.af.a(SourceFile:1181)
    at com.smartxls.ss.af.a(SourceFile:1198)
    at com.smartxls.ss.aj.a(SourceFile:7884)
    at com.smartxls.ss.aj.a(SourceFile:7874)
    at com.smartxls.WorkBook.write(SourceFile:2363)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use getLock/releaseLock to sync the background thread calculations.

```
            try
            {
                workbook.getLock();
                workbook.read(...);
                ...
                workbook.write(...);
            }
            finally
            {
                workbook.releaseLock();
            }
```